# Problem when saving a file in a folder, which comes from type byte [] on the server when using WriteAllBytes in C #

Tags: c#, arrays, file, streamwriter, production

I have the following function:

```
 private void saveImageByteInFolder( byte[] img)
 {
                var path = Server.MapPath("~/Images/prueba.jpg");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, img);
  }
```

In localhost it works fine, but when I try it in production, it says error: [object Object]

I've also tried with this code, but it also gives me the same error:

```
  byte[] img
  using (Stream file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path_img))
        {
           file.Write(img, 0, img.Length);
        }
```

I guess it has to do with the issue of permissions, but there must be another way to implement it through code to make it work.

If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: What is the error? Is this some type of IIS application - if so your app pool user will require rights to the folder.

Comment: yes, of IIS, 
But will there be another way without manipulating in the server?

Comment: Does the folder `Images` exist?

Comment: if the folder exists

Comment: Which of the listed exceptions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_WriteAllBytes_System_String_System_Byte___ is being thrown (note that 'I don't know' is not a valid response - you'll need to debug the server side or check the logs if you don't know)?